# duplicate keys conflict in using activerecord-import with apartment gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, apartment-gem

I'm using `activerecord-import` gem to import many records in one DB insert, in the same project I'm using `apartment` gem to create and use multi postgres schemas and switch between many schemas realtime ...

the issue is sometimes after import records, will be conflict in unique records ids!

> ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: PG::UniqueViolation: ERROR:  duplicate
>   key value violates unique constraint "table_name_" DETAIL:  Key
>   (id)=(43) already exists.

this conflict only happening by using active-record import gem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After debugging many cases ... I realized that the issue is coming from active record `sequence_name` after switching schema by apartment gem ..

let's say we have two schemas `schema_1` and `schema_2`, after switching schema by apartment gem, it doesn't change the sequence_name of DB table!!, like following ...

```
Apartment::Tenant.switch! :schema_1
TableName.sequence_name => "schema_1.table_names_id_seq"
Apartment::Tenant.switch! :schema_2
TableName.sequence_name => "schema_1.table_names_id_seq"
```

so after switching to `schema_2` and using `active-record-import` gem it takes the sequence id from old schema! (schema_1) ... and could be this id is already used in the schema_2 ... and will be `PG::UniqueViolation` error ...

I tried creating records by `TableName.create` or `.save` ... and it works correctly! and getting new sequence ids from current schema (schema_2) ..

it seems like `.create` and `.save` refresh sequence_name automatically but active-records-import doesn't !

I solved this by refreshing `sequence_name` manually before using `.import` , by:

```
TableName.reset_sequence_name
```